# Calculating time difference from unix $date

Tags: python, date, unix, time

I have pairs of timestamps from the unix date:

```
alvas@ubi:~$ date
Wed May 20 01:04:43 CEST 2015
```

**How can I calculate the time difference between the pairs of timestamp?**

**Note:** I don't have the full datetime stamp from `$date` but only the time in `hr:min:sec` left in my logfile.

For example, `timediff(start, end)`:

```
timediff('11:12:10', '19:58:50')
timediff('15:17:09', '03:11:10')
```

[out]:

```
31600
42841
```

[out2]:

```
8 hrs 46 mins 40 secs (31600 secs)
11 hrs 54 mins 1 secs (42841 secs)
```

**In the case that `end < start`, treat it as the next day.**

I've tried the script below but **is there an easier way to do that**?

```
def timediff(start, end):
    start_hr, start_min, start_sec = map(float, start.split(':'))
    end_hr, end_min, end_sec = map(float, end.split(':'))

    if end_hr < start_hr:
        end_hr = end_hr + 24

    if end_min < start_min:
        end_min = end_min + 60
        end_hr -= 1

    if end_sec < start_sec:
        end_sec = end_sec + 60
        end_min -= 1

    num_hrs = end_hr - start_hr
    num_mins = end_min - start_min
    num_secs = end_sec - start_sec

    total_seconds = 60*60*num_hrs + 60*num_mins+num_secs

    total_time = " ".join([str(num_hrs), 'hrs', str(num_mins), 'mins', str(num_secs), 'secs'])

    return total_seconds, total_time




print timediff('11:12:10', '19:58:50')
print timediff('15:17:09', '03:11:10')
```

[out]:

```
(31600.0, '8.0 hrs 46.0 mins 40.0 secs')
(42841.0, '11.0 hrs 54.0 mins 1.0 secs')
```

When I tried `dateutil.parser.parse`:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse
>>> dtparse('19:58:50') - dtparse('11:12:10')
datetime.timedelta(0, 31600)
>>> dtparse('03:11:10') - dtparse('15:17:09')
datetime.timedelta(-1, 42841)
```

Comment: No love for [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html) module. You can simply subtract two `datetime` objects and get the info from the returned `timedelta` object.

Comment: This question is more suitable for [Code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: its no longer clear what you expect to happen when time1 > time2 ... should the order be flipped or time1 gets -1 day?

Comment: @JoranBeasley, In the case that end < start, treat it as the next day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dateutil.parser(`pip install python-dateutil`) can parse just about anything ... and its timezone aware

```
from dateutil.parser import parse as dtparse
print dtparse("Wed May 20 01:04:43 CEST 2015") - dtparse("Wed May 20 00:02:43 CEST 2015")


>>> print dtparse("Fri May 22 01:04:43 CEST 2015") - dtparse("Wed May 20 00:02:43
CEST 2015")
2 days, 1:02:00

>>> print dtparse("15:22:36") - dtparse("12:00:45")
3:21:51 # 3 hours, 21 minutes, 51 seconds
```

here ... this will work if you dont know which timestamp is later ...

```
def tdiff(t1,t2):
    if t1 > t2:t1,t2 = t2,t1
    return t2-t1

print tdiff(dtparse('11:12:10'), dtparse('19:58:50'))
```

if you want to subtract a day in the event the order is wrong try this

```
def tdiff(t1,t2):
    if t1 > t2:t1 - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return t2-t1
```

Comment: I don't have the full datetime stamp from $date but only the time in hr:min:sec left in my logfile.

Comment: cool, it even works even it gets to the next day from 3pm to 3am.

Answer (score 1):

Probably easier to use [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
import datetime

def timediff(t1, t2):
    d1=datetime.datetime.strptime(t1, "%H:%M:%S")
    d2=datetime.datetime.strptime(t2, "%H:%M:%S")
    if d2<d1:
        d1-=datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    return ((d2-d1).total_seconds(), str(d2-d1))

>>> timediff('11:12:10', '19:58:50')
(31600.0, '8:46:40')
>>> timediff('15:17:09', '03:11:10')
(42841.0, '11:54:01')
```

Comment: Though `.seconds` will work correctly in this context, I would still recommend using `.total_seconds()`, which actually means the total seconds in the duration. Secondly there's no need of  `today` and `hms()` here, simply parse the strings using `datetime.datetime.strptime`, compare them in `if` condition and you're done.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Of course you are correct. Edit made.